# Cómo borrar todos los archivos .json de unas 2.000 carpetas a la vez

Tags: batch, windows10

Tengo unas 2.000 carpetas con fotos y archivos .json. Quisiera borrar únicamente los archivos .json de todas las carpetas al mismo tiempo con un archivo .bat.

Gracias.

Comment: This is Stack Overflow in spanish. Maybe you want https://stackoverflow.com/ or translate your post.

Answer (score 0):

quizás esto te ayude un poco. Especifica el directorio donde querrás que se eliminen los archivos con el formato establecido.

```
cd "C:\..\..."
del /F /S /Q *.json
```